# Adding lines in algebraic geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a basic question. In some algebraic geometry [texts](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9602006.pdf) (see p. 4), authors will write $L_1+L_2$ where $L_1,L_2$ are lines on some variety. This isn't notation I have seen used before in Hartshorne and I couldn't find a reference as to what it means. Can someone clarify?

Thanks.

Comment: I think Reid is thinking of the lines as divisors on the surface $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context, the ambient variety $X$ is a surface, so the lines $L_i$ are divisors and the addition is addition as divisors on $X$. If you're working out of Hartshorne, divisors are covered for the first time in section II.6.

Comment: I realized the answer right as this was posted and others were commenting. For some reason, I was thinking that $X$ was dimension three which didn't make much sense. Thanks!